# How to sort/select distinct in XSLT when creating a header/details XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I have a file with a header record and one to many detail records. I need to create the same header record, along with the last detail record for a given policy number. How do I write the XSLT to both sort and select the first record?

I have tried placing a hard coded value in between the "for-each" statements within the XSLT to see where the code breaks. Anything placed after the second "for-each" doesn't display. I have searched high and low there to see if anyone can handle a header with multiple details, but I couldn't find an answer to this question.

This is what I'm receiving (simplified - there are a lot more fields):

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://CORE.BizTalk.Applications.Schemas.PolicyFF">
    <Header>
        <RecordType>RecordType</RecordType>
        <RecordID>RecordID</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>PolicyNumber</PolicyNumber>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>1</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>ABC 0000018 00</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>2</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>DEF0000019</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>3</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>DEF0000019</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>3</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>ABC 0000018 00</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
</ns0:Root>
```

The output has the identical layout, but I only want to see this, since the RecordID is the last RecordID for both policies (sorted descending by RecordID for each policy):

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://CORE.BizTalk.Applications.Schemas.PolicyFF">
    <Header>
        <RecordType>RecordType</RecordType>
        <RecordID>RecordID</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>PolicyNumber</PolicyNumber>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>3</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>DEF0000019</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <RecordType>POL</RecordType>
        <RecordID>3</RecordID>
        <PolicyNumber>ABC 0000018 00</PolicyNumber>
    </Detail>
</ns0:Root>
```

This is the XSLT I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://CORE.BizTalk.Applications.Schemas.PolicyFF">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:key name="policy" match="Root/Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:Root" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns0:Root">
        <ns0:Root>
            <Header>
                <RecordType>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Header/RecordType/text()" />
                </RecordType>
                <RecordID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Header/RecordID/text()" />
                </RecordID>
                <PolicyNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Header/PolicyNumber/text()" />
                </PolicyNumber>
            </Header>
            <xsl:for-each select="Detail">
                <xsl:for-each select="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1])]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('policy', PolicyNumber)">
                        <xsl:sort order="descending" select="RecordID" data-type="text"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <Detail>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
                            </Detail>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am currently only getting the header record with the XSLT above.

@Martin-Honnen: I need to sort by RecordID descending. I took your first and second XSLTs and turned it into one, but I'm still only getting the header record. Suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://CORE.BizTalk.Applications.PPPL.TrisuraReports.Schemas.PolicyFF">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:key name="policy" match="Root/Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Detail[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1]))]"/>

    <xsl:template match="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1])]">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('policy', PolicyNumber)">
            <xsl:sort select="RecordID" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1, if "with the last detail record" means last in the input, I would simply use the identity transformation template plus a template preventing the copying of any `Detail` not being the last of its group defined by the key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="policy" match="Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[last()]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuP

If you need to sort by the `RecordID` then in one template for the first or last item of the group you can sort all items in the group and output the last in descending:

```
  <xsl:template match="Detail[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1]))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1])]">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('policy', PolicyNumber)">
          <xsl:sort select="RecordID" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuP/1 is the full online sample and has

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="policy" match="Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1]))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1])]">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('policy', PolicyNumber)">
          <xsl:sort select="RecordID" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried to respond in a comment, but apparently it was too long. Can you please see my edited response?

Comment: Well, your root element is in a namespace while the `Detail` elements are not, so either use the key as I have shown `<xsl:key name="policy" match="Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />` which does not reference that root element or make sure you use `<xsl:key name="policy" match="ns0:Root/Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />` where you have `xmlns:ns0="http://CORE.BizTalk.Applications.Schemas.PolicyFF"` declared in the stylesheet as well. Otherwise the key is not built for your input sample where you have elements in different namespaces.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the key to match on ns0:Root/Detail worked. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="policy" match="Detail" use="PolicyNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
        <!-- for each distinct policy -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Detail[count(. | key('policy', PolicyNumber)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- sort current group -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('policy', PolicyNumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="RecordID" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <!-- return the record with highest RecordID -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```